# What's counted in your item limit?

Tags: mass-effect

I just got an alert that I'm nearing my item limit.  However, I'm fairly certain my character is not carrying anywhere near 150 items by themselves.  So, what all gets counted in this limit?

Here's the item locations I can think of which may be counted.  I'd like to know which of these are included, and if there are any others:

- PC's backpack (carried, but not equipped)
- PC's equipped items
- Mods installed on PC's equipped items
- Shore party NPCs' equipped items
- Mods installed on shore party NPCs' equipped items
- Reserve NPCs' equipped items
- Mods installed on reserve NPCs' equipped items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mass effect inventory is shared - what's Shepard's is everyone else's too.

That said, the only thing that *doesn't* count against the limit are those items which you have equipped.

It might be time to goop some Avenger's down to Omnigel, or make bank offloading your ill-gotten guns to the nearest shop owner. Clear out some guns, armor, and mods, and you'll have plenty of space again in no time.

Comment: "...those items which you have equipped" meaning just the PC, or also NPCs?

Comment: @Iszi squadmates count also.